# Which product not available in magento why it's job is created

Tags: magento-1.7, odoo-9

Which product is i have already deleted from magento 1 then import product in odoo then why deleted product job is created ? and then this job is failed and raise this error :  **TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'**

This error occured in attribute value get None, But in this problem deleted product job should not be created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because some product are not created completely, 
so there in product creation some data are missed so that is not display in magento backend.

But that product is already in **magento database** so it's job is created.